# How to add a date picker activity to a fragment in android studio (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-datepicker

I am new to Android Studio and am not sure how it works. I want to be able to select a date from my date picker which is in a fragment but not sure how to do this.

My main activity contains a bottom navigation to all 4 fragments

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {item ->
    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            println("home pressed")
            replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_social -> {
            println("social pressed")
            replaceFragment(SocialFragment())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_calendar -> {
            println("calendar pressed")
            replaceFragment(CalendarFragment())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_account -> {
            println("account pressed")
            replaceFragment(AccountFragment())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

And in the Calendar Fragment, I have created a DatePicker as below:

```
<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/Date_Picker"
            android:datePickerMode="calendar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_frame"
            android:headerBackground="#FFFFFF"
            android:translationY="-80dp"></DatePicker>
```

I want to be able to select a date from the calendar but I don't know where to put this code. I have the following code for selecting a date but not sure where to put it:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_calendar)

    val datePicker = findViewById<DatePicker>(R.id.Date_Picker)
    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    datePicker.init(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))

    { view, year, month, day ->
        val month = month + 1
        val msg = "You selected: $day/$month/$year"
        Toast.makeText(this@fragment_calendar, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to create a new activity and call the calendar fragment or should I be putting this code within the calendar fragment? 
Thanks

I have added the code below but it still doesn't do anything when I click on a date on my datepicker.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val datePicker = view?.findViewById<DatePicker>(R.id.Date_Picker)
    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    println(today)
    datePicker?.init(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), object : DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener{
        override fun onDateChanged(
            view: DatePicker?,
            year: Int,
            monthOfYear: Int,
            dayOfMonth: Int
            ) {
                print(dayOfMonth)
            }
        })
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onDateChangeListener` in the same `fragment`/`Activity` where you have initialised it. You can add the below code in onCreate:

```
 datePicker.init(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), object : DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener{
            override fun onDateChanged(
                view: DatePicker?,
                year: Int,
                monthOfYear: Int,
                dayOfMonth: Int
            ) {
                //Set the date here
                Log.d("DATE", "Date Listener called")
            }

        })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added an onCreate function in the CalendarFragment.kt fragment and added this code in but 'datePicker' isn't recognised and is coloured in red. What do you think the problem could be? Thanks

Comment: @cstephlee have you added this after you have initialised your datePicker or before. You might need to surround this around an if statement to check the versions

Comment: I've initialised with an if statement but it still doesn't work. I tried to print the date when it changes but it doesn't print anything to the console. I have added the code I tried in the post

Comment: @cstephlee check my updated answer you can use listener inside init itself. If my answer helped you please accept it as answer and upvote it.

Comment: I modified it but it still doesn't do anything when I select a date

Comment: are you not getting callback to that listener?

Comment: I have tried the same and you get a callback to the listener when you select date.

Comment: nope, nothing happens when I select a date. Is this something to do with it being in a fragment instead of an activity?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with fragment or activity, how are you checking? Can you add a log statement inside listener and add a break point and see if its going there.

Comment: Add a log statement as shown in answer and add a break point to that line and debug and see if it breaks after date is selected

Comment: I have added the log line and debugged it, I don't think it's going into this part of the code at all. Note: I changed the 'calendar.get(Calendar.month)' to 'today.get(Calendar.month)' and did the same for day of month as 'calendar' wasn't initialised as anything.

Comment: I also have this error:
Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))
Has this got anything to do with it?

Comment: No that is a javascript file. I don think it has something to do. You can try in different emulator or in a real device

Comment: your coe in question is right for today everywhere you should have `today` as I have added in my updated answer